# Java Android Animations

Tags: java, android, animation

At the moment I'm able to play an animation onCreate and the change that animation to another onClick.
What I'd like to do is after say 3 cycles of the first animation revert back to continuously looping the first one.
It should be pretty easy but I'm really only just starting out.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    ImageView robocatView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.roboCat);
    robocatView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robocat_idle);
    AnimationDrawable robocatAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) robocatView.getBackground();
    robocatAnimation.start();
}

public void feed(View view){
    ImageView robocatView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.roboCat);
    robocatView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.robocat_feed);
    AnimationDrawable robocatAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) robocatView.getBackground();
    robocatAnimation.start();
}
```

Comment: Could you change your profile photo, please? This is not a strip club

Comment: Absolutely agree with @ArtooDetoo, remove this prof picture please, lack of seriousness.

Comment: use robocatAnimation.setOneShot(false) for continuous animation